# Polygon labeling algorithm for a country map

Tags: text, geometry, maps, polygon

How would you implement an algorithm to place country labels in a map like on the picture below?

[image: Europa Universalis 4 map]

I thought about decomposing a polygon into x-monotone parts, picking the biggest one and averaging out the top polyline with the bottom one to get the general flow of the text, but I don't think it will handle corner cases such as with the Ottomans on the picture.

The only criteria is: it should look good, so no upside down or intersecting text. The label should try to fill as much area as possible.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you need something that is fully automated or is a tool-assisted approach fine (it does 90% of the work and a user fine tunes if needed). If the later, I'd probably just set it up so you can manually adjust it. Who knows, perhaps being able to manual adjust it will give some insights on how to fully automate those adjustments.

Comment: I need it fully automated, because the map can change over time and the labels should update accordingly.